# iOS deletion and reorder controls -- change the location within a cell?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

I am wondering if there is any way to move these controls -- say up or down, or left or right, from their default locations.

Comment: I would suggest laying out your cell for these states to accommodate the controls. End users are aware of where these controls should be naturally and changing that may feel odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it, but it's a lot of hacky hassle to do, so that you skirt around using private APIs. Your better off redesigning your cell to accommodate these controls, either statically or when your table view cell enters these modes, using `willTransitionToState:` and `didTransitionToState:` in a UITableViewCell subclass.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. At least not through any sane means.